# Distribute itself as seeds?

Tags: meaning

What does 'distributes itself as seeds' mean in the following sentence:

> Imagine an exhibition that comes to life. That distributes itself as seeds among those who visit, creating engagement and outreach.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of analogy. The ideas created by the exhibition are likened to seeds. The exhibition creates ideas in the minds of the onlookers. Those ideas later grow into actions of new outreach and further discussion among those who attended the exhibition, just as seeds when scattered grow into new plants and communities of plants.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analogy)
> *analogy*
> a : comparison of two otherwise unlike things based on resemblance of a particular aspect
> b : resemblance in some particulars between things otherwise unlike

Comment: Welcome to this site. I have answered although I feel the question is best asked in the English Language Learners site.